# Can't succeed in linking an OpenGL program

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, glsl, shader

Here are my (very simple) shaders:

```
protected String [] codeTransformateurSommets = {
    "#version 400 core",
    "void main(void) {",
        "const vec4 vertices[3]=vec4[3](vec4(0.25,-0.25,0.5,1.0),",
        "                           vec4(-0.25,-0.25,0.5,1.0),",
        "                           vec4(0.25,0.25,0.5,1.0));",
        "gl_position=vertices[gl_VertexID];",
    "}"
};

protected String [] codeTransformateurFragments = {
    "#version 400 core",
    "out vec4 color;",
    "void main(void) {",
        "color=vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);",
    "}"
};
```

Here's how I try to get a program :

```
private int créeProgrammeOpenGL(){
    IntBuffer résultatEditionLiens;
    int transformateurSommets,transformateurFaces;
    int programme;

    transformateurSommets = chargeTransformateur(GL4.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,codeTransformateurSommets);
    transformateurFaces = chargeTransformateur(GL4.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, codeTransformateurFragments);
    programme = gl4.glCreateProgram();
    gl4.glAttachShader(programme, transformateurSommets);
    gl4.glAttachShader(programme, transformateurFaces);
    gl4.glLinkProgram(programme);
    if(programme!=0) {
        résultatEditionLiens=IntBuffer.allocate(1);
        gl4.glGetProgramiv(programme, GL4.GL_LINK_STATUS, résultatEditionLiens);
        if (résultatEditionLiens.get(0) == 0) {
            gl4.glDeleteProgram(programme);
            throw new RuntimeException("Erreur à la création du programme!!");
        } else {
            gl4.glUseProgram(programme);
            gl4.glDeleteShader(transformateurSommets);
            gl4.glDeleteShader(transformateurFaces);
        }
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Erreur à la création du programme!!");
    }

    return(programme);
}

public static int chargeTransformateur(int type, String [] codeTransformateur){
    int transformateur,i,j;
    IntBuffer résultatCompilation;

    transformateur = gl4.glCreateShader(type);
    if(transformateur!=0) {
        // création réussie : lui indiquer le code source
        gl4.glShaderSource(transformateur,codeTransformateur.length,codeTransformateur,null);

        // compiler le code source
        gl4.glCompileShader(transformateur);

        // récupérer le diagnostic de création du shader
        byte [] infoLog=new byte[10000];
        int [] taille=new int[100];
        gl4.glGetShaderInfoLog(transformateur,1000,taille,0,infoLog,0);

        // récupérer le résultat de la compilation
        résultatCompilation=IntBuffer.allocate(1);
        gl4.glGetShaderiv(transformateur,GL4.GL_COMPILE_STATUS,résultatCompilation);
        if(résultatCompilation.get(0)==0) {
            // la compilation a échoué!
            throw new RuntimeException("Erreur à la compilation du shader!!"+"\r\n"+"\r\n"+codeTransformateur+"\r\n"+"\r\n"+infoLog.toString()+"\r\n"+"\r\n"+"\r\n");
        }
    } else {
        // la création est un échec!
        throw new RuntimeException("Erreur à la création du nom du shader!!"+"\r\n"+codeTransformateur);
    }

    return(transformateur);
}
```

And the result is a GL_LINK_STATUS set to false when `glLinkProgram` returns.

My investigations :

- calling `glGetShaderiv` with parameter `GL_COMPILE_STATUS` returns true for both shaders.
- calling `glGetProgramiv` function with parameter `GL_ATTACHED_SHADERS` returns 1 after the first attachment and 2 after the second.

Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can use [`glGetProgramInfoLog`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetProgramInfoLog.xhtml) you retrieve any error/diagnostic info regarding the link process.

Comment: Gave me the following error : "n(0):error C5145:must write to gl_Position". I changed `gl_position` in my vertex shader to `gl_Position` but I still get the same error message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major is is, that you've to set the source code to the shader object by [`glShaderSource`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glShaderSource.xhtml) rather than reading the source code string from a shader object by [`glGetShaderSource`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetShaderSource.xhtml).
See [Java Code Examples for com.jogamp.opengl.GL2.glShaderSource()](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=com.jogamp.opengl.GL2&method=glShaderSource).

What you actually do, is to compile "empty" shader objects (of course with out any errors). But linking fails, because the vertex shader does not write to `gl_Position` (of course, because it is "empty").

---

If you want to create and initialize an array of `vec4`, then the correct syntax is:
(See [Array constructors](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Array_constructors))

```c
const vec4 vertices[3] = vec4[3](
    vec4(0.25,-0.25,0.5,1.0),
    vec4(-0.25,-0.25,0.5,1.0),
    vec4(0.25,0.25,0.5,1.0));
```

Furthermore, [OpenGL Shading Language (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language) is case sensitive. It is [`gl_Position`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_Position.xhtml) rather than `gl_position`:

<s>`gl_position=vertices[gl_VertexID];`</s>

```c
gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID];
```

---

I recommend to get the compile error messages by [`glGetShaderInfoLog`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetProgramInfoLog.xhtml). See [Java Code Examples for org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glCompileShader()](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20&method=glCompileShader)

Comment: Already noticed the "p" in `gl_Position`. Corrected the array declaration by pasting your code : no improvements... Calling `gl4.glGetShaderInfoLog` after shaders compilations results in an `infoLog` only filled with "0".

Comment: Added "\n" at the end of every lines in the shaders : no improvements.

Comment: And after each shader compilation, the `glGetError`function systematically returns 0 (`GL_NO_ERROR`).

Comment: And the function `glGetDebugMessageLog`returns "0" even if `glEnable(GL4.GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT)` is executed.

Comment: With `glShaderSource`, the shader doesn't compile, but the result of `glGetShaderInfoLog` is now unclear : `infoLog.toString` returns [B@780e767d...

Comment: To change from `glGetShaderSource` to `glShaderSource`, I have had to modify the code as well. You can see this new code in the question I edited.

Comment: Additionnaly, adding '\n' to each shader line led me to a program linked without error! Thnaks for your help!